# Symfony 2 with custom config yaml file

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, bundle

I have created a new bundle and in my project and followed the instructions on [how to expose the configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html).

This part works fine, but when I try to add a new yaml file (named after my bundle, so that I could potentially create similar named files in other bundle config folders and merge them in) in the bundles config using the same tags and add this into the extension class for loading I get the error:

```
InvalidArgumentException: There is no extension able to load the configuration for "foo_bar_notify" (in /path/to/symfony/src/Foo/Bar/NotifyBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/notify.yml). Looked for namespace "foo_bar_notify", found none
```

Can someone point out what I have missed please (or doing wrong).

*Code snippets;*
Configuration class

```
public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
{
    $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
    $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('foo_bar_notify');

    $rootNode
        ->children()
            ->arrayNode('roles')
                ->requiresAtLeastOneElement()
                ->prototype('array')
                    ->children()
                        ->scalarNode('name')
                            ->isRequired(true)
                        ->end()
                        ->scalarNode('description')
                        ->end()
                        ->arrayNode('placeholders')
                            ->prototype('scalar')->end()
                        ->end()
                        ->booleanNode('html')
                            ->isRequired()
                            ->defaultValue(true)
                        ->end()
                        ->scalarNode('template')
                            ->isRequired(true)
                        ->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ->end();

    return $treeBuilder;
}
```

Extension class

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $processor = new Processor();
    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $config = $processor->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    $loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
    $loader->load('services.yml');
    $loader->load('foo_bar_notify.yml');

    $container->setParameter('notify', $config);
}

public function getAlias()
{
    return 'foo_bar_notify';
}
```

Main Config file

```
foo_bar_notify:
    roles:
        software_developer:
            name: Alice
            description: Foo
            placeholders:
                - $name
                - $email
            html: true
            template: 'some/path'
        super_developer:
            name: Malfoy
            description: bar
            html: false
            template: 'some/path/over/here'
```

Custom yaml (notify.yml)

```
foo_bar_notify:
    roles:
        core_developer:
            name: core
            html: true
            template: 'some/path'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got a solution using the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22636925/symfony-2-loading-custom-configuration-file?rq=1).

My extension class now looks like this;

```
private $configFileName = 'notify.yml';

public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{  
    // see if there are any other notify.yml files defined in other bundles
    $finder = new \Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder();
    $finder
        ->directories()
        ->in($container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir') . '/../src/Foo/Bar/*Bundle/Resources')
        ->path('config');

    foreach ($finder as $c_dir) {
        $absolute_path = $c_dir.'/'.$this->configFileName;
        if (file_exists($absolute_path)) {
            $to_add = array_values(Yaml::parse(file_get_contents($absolute_path)));
            $configs[0] = $this->merge($configs[0], $to_add[0]);
        }
    }

    $processor = new Processor();
    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $config = $processor->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    $loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
    $loader->load('services.yml');

    // set the processed values as a parameter
    $container->setParameter('notify', $config);
}
```

Comment: Hi! I asked that linked question, and found better solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22667580/309240